# how to set color in ejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

how can i set color of title to color stored in my database i am using this code but this code is showing hexcolor code

```
 <div class="inner">
              <p><%=notes.heading.color = notes.color  %></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: what title? `style="color:<%= notes.color || 'inherit' %>"`

Comment: my title that i stored in my database for example 'my birthday' is title

Comment: I only see a div with a class and child a p tag, not anything related to a title, need to make it more clear

Comment: title i mean heading which is notes.heading i am sorry for confusion

Comment: it is not working              <div class="inner">
                                        <p><%=notes.heading.style="color:<%= notes.color%>"%> 
                                           
                                  </p>
            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for my problem:

```
<div class="inner">
    <p style="color: <%=notes.color%>"><%=notes.heading%> </p>
</div>
```